# Add space around series image in pgfplots legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to add space around the image in a legend. MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend columns=-1]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \addlegendentry{Parabola}
    \addplot[only marks] {x};
    \addlegendentry{Line}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Current Output:

[image: current]

Desired Output:

[image]

The best approach I have come up with is to make give the second series a white line in addition to its black marks, but this looks odd if the background is not white or the line crosses over other series.

Comment: Consider accepting the provided solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do whatever you want by defining your own legend style if you don't want to tweak all the time.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
  my legend/.style={legend image code/.code={%
    \draw[##1]plot coordinates{(0cm,0cm)(0.3cm,0cm)(0.6cm,0cm)};}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \addlegendentry{Parabola}
    \addplot[only marks,my legend] {x};
    \addlegendentry{Line}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More details are given on page 260 in the manual.

Comment: How can I get empty space using this command? If I make "my legend" style only plot one of the three points in your MWE, then the spacing is the same as before

Comment: @user1476176 For example you can add `sharp plot,draw opacity=0` to the legend options just what you though before.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show how to do this? It would make a better record for anyone curious in future.

Comment: +1: Is the order of the legend entries automatically chosen? Vertical or horizontal is what I mean.